# What's a better way to look up information in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

Does anyone know of a "better/cleaner/faster" way to write this? I have to do it for 29 different brands (Acura, Honda, Toyota, etc) but each brand has their own specific warranty length in miles and time.

```
if ($row['make'] == "Acura" && $row['mileage'] <= "70000" && date("Y")-6 < $year) {
    $warr_Man = TRUE;
} elseif ($row['make'] == "Audi" && $row['mileage'] <= "50000" && date("Y")-5 < $year) {
    $warr_Man = TRUE;
}
```

Something is wrong! I inputted in all the correct data, but am getting an error: "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in carcityofdanbury.com/New/vehicle.php on line 331"

```
    $make = row['make'];
    $year = $row['year'];
    $mileage = row['mileage'];

    $arr=[
        ['make' => Acura, 'mileage' => 70000, 'date' => 6],
        ['make' => Audi, 'mileage' => 50000, 'date' => 5],
        ['make' => BMW, 'mileage' => 50000, 'date' => 4],
        ['make' => Buick, 'mileage' => 60000, 'date' => 5],
        ['make' => Cadillac, 'mileage' => 60000, 'date' => 5],
        ['make' => Chevrolet, 'mileage' => 60000, 'date' => 5],
        ['make' => Chrysler, 'mileage' => 36000, 'date' => 3],
        ['make' => Dodge, 'mileage' => 36000, 'date' => 3],
        ['make' => Ford, 'mileage' => 60000, 'date' => 5],
        ['make' => GMC, 'mileage' => 60000, 'date' => 5],
        ['make' => Honda, 'mileage' => 60000, 'date' => 5],
        ['make' => Hummer, 'mileage' => 60000, 'date' => 5],
        ['make' => Hyundai, 'mileage' => 50000, 'date' => 5],
        ['make' => Infiniti, 'mileage' => 70000, 'date' => 6],
        ['make' => Isuzu, 'mileage' => 75000, 'date' => 7],
        ['make' => Jaguar, 'mileage' => 50000, 'date' => 4],
        ['make' => Jeep, 'mileage' => 36000, 'date' => 3],
        ['make' => Kia, 'mileage' => 75000, 'date' => 5],
        ['make' => Land Rover, 'mileage' => 50000, 'date' => 4],
        ['make' => Lexus, 'mileage' => 70000, 'date' => 6],
        ['make' => Lincoln, 'mileage' => 70000, 'date' => 6],
        ['make' => Mazda, 'mileage' => 50000, 'date' => 4],
        ['make' => Mercedes-Benz, 'mileage' => 50000, 'date' => 4],
        ['make' => Mercury, 'mileage' => 60000, 'date' => 5],
        ['make' => Mini, 'mileage' => 50000, 'date' => 4],
        ['make' => Mitsubishi, 'mileage' => 100000, 'date' => 10],
        ['make' => Nissan, 'mileage' => 60000, 'date' => 5],
        ['make' => Porsche, 'mileage' => 50000, 'date' => 4],
        ['make' => Scion, 'mileage' => 60000, 'date' => 5],
        ['make' => Subaru, 'mileage' => 60000, 'date' => 5],
        ['make' => Suzuki, 'mileage' => 100000, 'date' => 7],
        ['make' => Mercury, 'mileage' => 60000, 'date' => 5],
        ['make' => Toyota, 'mileage' => 60000, 'date' => 5],
        ['make' => Volkswagen, 'mileage' => 60000, 'date' => 5],
        ['make' => Volvo, 'mileage' => 50000, 'date' => 4],
    ];
    $warr_Man = false;

    foreach($rows as $row) {
        foreach($arr as $v) {
                $warr_Man = ($make == $v['make'] && $mileage <= $v['mileage'] && date("Y")-$v['date'] < $year) ? true : false;

            if($warr_Man)    //if matches break.
        break;
        }
        if(!$warr_Man)    //if one row not pass then break.
    break;
    }
```

Comment: would `$warr_Man` be false if only one brand fails the test? Where does the data come from?

Comment: Yes. 
  } else {
   $warr_Man = FALSE;
  }

Comment: time to learn the magic of arrays or databases.

Comment: @bassxzero and classes/objects/models!

Comment: Anyone, I'm attempting to learn but am stuck on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want your code to do is determine whether or not the warranty is still valid on a car whose mileage and year of manufacture you've retrieved from (I'm assuming) a database.

Consider the array you've defined, `$arr`: It's like a miniature database itself that stores information about warranty limits, indexed by the make of car. This suggests it would be better structured as a *two*-dimensional associative array with car makes as keys:

```
// An associative array of warranty-limit information, indexed by make of car
$warranty_limits = [
    'Acura' => [
        'mileage' => 70000,
        'years' => 6
    ],
    'Audi' => [
        'mileage' => 50000,
        'years' => 5
    ],
    'BMW' => [
        'mileage' => 50000,
        'years' => 4
    ],
    // ...
];
```

This allows us to quickly look up the warranty information for a specific make, like this:

```
$warranty_limit = &$warranty_limits['Audi'];
```

(The ampersand character means we are asking the interpreter for a [*reference*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatare.php) to the array element, which saves it from wasting time making a copy of the element for us. If you find this confusing, you can just leave the ampersand out—the performance difference in this case is negligible.)

This is much more efficient than iterating through the array element-by-element, as you're doing currently in your `foreach` block, since we're using PHP's ability to quickly look up an array element by its key to take us directly to the data we need.

Once we've done this, we can access the details of the warranty as elements of the subarray we've retrieved:

```
$audi_mileage_limit = $warranty_limit['mileage'];
$audi_years_limit   = $warranty_limit['years'];
```

---

With the `$warranty_limits` array defined as above, your code might look like this:

```
// Fetch the data for this car
$make    = $row['make'];
$mileage = $row['mileage'];
$year    = $row['year'];

// Assume its warranty is not valid
$warranty_valid = FALSE;

// Check whether we have warranty information for this make of car
if (array_key_exists($make, $warranty_limits)) {
    // We do; retrieve it
    $warranty_limit = &$warranty_limits[$make];

    // If this car is still within the manufacturer's limits, its warranty
    // is valid
    if ($mileage <= $warranty_limit['mileage'] and
        (date("Y") - $warranty_limit['years']) < $year) {
        $warranty_valid = TRUE;
    }
}
else {
    // This make of car is unknown to us; handle this error case
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data for those cars is not yet in a structured data set, put it into one!
This is the simplest form: an array.

```
<?php
$makes = Array(
              Array(
                "name"=>"Acura", 
                "mileage" =>70000,
                "years" => 6
               ),
              Array(
                "name"=>"Audi", 
                "mileage" =>50000,
                "years" => 5
               )
         );

print_r($makes);

$warr_Man = false;

   // test-data that will come from a db I suppose
   $row['make'] = "Audi";
   $row['mileage'] = 4000;
   $year = 2017;

foreach($makes as $make) {
    if ($row['make'] == $make['name'] && $row['mileage'] <= $make['mileage'] && date("Y")-$make['years'] < $year) {
        // you might want to turn around the logic here: if mileage>mileage set $warr_Man to false
        $warr_Man = true;
    }
}
echo "warr_Man: ".$warr_Man;
?>
```

Note: this is the simplest implementation, not the most beautiful. This case could be *the* example for the introduction to [OOP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php): Your cars are objects with a certain set of properties.

Answer (score 0):

save the compared items as an array $arr, then use foreach to check them.

```
$arr=[['make' => Acura, 'mileage' => 70000, 'date' => 6], .....];
$warr_Man = false;
foreach($rows as $row)
{
    foreach($arr as $v)
    {
         $warr_Man = ($row['make'] == $v['make'] && $row['mileage'] <= $v['mileage'] && date("Y")-$v['date'] < $year) ? true : false;
         if($warr_Man)    //if matches break.
            break;
    }
    if(!$warr_Man)    //if one row not pass then break.
        break;
}
```